# stream wifi camera to android

Tags: android, video, rtsp

I'm trying to display the video stream from my wifi camera (SJ6 Legend) to an Android device.

When turning on the wifi from the camera and connecting to its network from my mac I can see the video stream from vlc simply by going to File -> Open Network and connecting to rtsp://MY_CAM_IP.

I then connect to the wifi from my android device and I tried using `MediaPlayer` or `VideoView` and it doesn't work.

vlc for android also doesn't display the video.

Just to make sure there is no problem playing RTSP I tried this file:
rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov

and it works fine on vlc for android and using `MediaPlayer`.

I also tried a vlc for android lib, that didn't work as well...

Relevant code:

In onCreate:

```
SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView) 
findViewById(R.id.am_surface_view);
mSurfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
mSurfaceHolder.setFixedSize(320, 240);
```

and:

```
/**
 * {@link MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener} interface methods
 */
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}

/**
 * {@link SurfaceHolder.Callback} interface methods
 */
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(final SurfaceHolder holder, final int format, final int width, final int height) {}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder sh) {

    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(sh);

//    Context context = getApplicationContext();
//    Map<String, String> headers = getRtspHeaders();
//    Uri source = Uri.parse(RTSP_URL);

    try {
        // Specify the IP camera's URL and auth headers.
//        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, source, headers);
//        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, source);
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(RTSP_URL); // RTSP_URL = "rtsp://MY_CAM_IP"

        // Begin the process of setting up a video stream.
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

    } catch (Exception e) {}
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder sh) {
    mMediaPlayer.release();
}
```

Anyone can point me to some solution???

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked when I turned off the phones' cellular network data.

Unfortunately I need to receive the camera stream and have a network connection to send the frames received but I guess that's another question...

Comment: You didn't happen to work out a way to connect to the camera without disabling the phones' cellular network data? (I'm crossing my fingers for a lead, because everything I'm trying to avoid this is failing!)

Comment: I did but it was a long time a go so I don't remember exactly what we did. What I do remember is that the solution made us support api 5.2 and above and that LG-G3 device supported wifi/cellular connection simultaneously without any changes